# Google Container Registry giving 'Access Denied' when trying to push Docker container

Tags: docker

So I'm trying to push my docker image to gcr.io/docker-url, but it's not working. I've tried the documentation that Google has, but that's still failed (https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#standalone_docker_credential_helper). I also tried:

```
docker login gcr.io
```

and

```
docker login us.gcr.io
```

Here's the command I run and my error:

```
docker push gcr.io/docker-url/jenkins/container
The push refers to repository [gcr.io/docker-url/jenkins/container]
d7ab52d2e8be: Pushing [==================================================>]   2.56kB
fae569eb21a4: Pushing  1.536kB
7a20d9096c74: Pushing [====>                                              ]  735.7kB/7.854MB
a26d457fd72d: Pushing [>                                                  ]  60.93kB/6.055MB
36f2fac55108: Pushing [>                                                  ]  502.8kB/49.16MB
4cd936335289: Waiting 
f1b5933fe4b5: Waiting 
denied: Access denied.
```

For reference, I used the json file to login. I even tried all of the StackOverflow answers I could find, but no luck there, either.

Comment: Does your user (or service account) have such permissions to write on Google Container Registry? .... I use to run the following command to authenticate for push/pull images: `docker login -u oauth2accesstoken -p "$(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://gcr.io`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else is running into this issue and can't figure it out, I fixed it by running this command:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file key-file.json
```

And then ran my docker push command and it pushed through.